# Paging results from google custom search service

Tags: webservices, serviceexecute

There is no 'MinItems' suboption, so what is the limit per request? How can I page through results, say like if I wanted the first 2k images from a search?

```
results = 
 ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", 
  "Search", {"Query" -> "Albrecht Altdorfer", MaxItems -> 2000, 
   "SearchType" -> "Image"}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

I tried using C.E.'s suggestion:

```
Do[
 idx = 0;
 b = Internal`Bag[];
 {t, res} = AbsoluteTiming[While[True,
    Check[
     Internal`StuffBag[b, 
      Normal[ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", 
         "Search", {"Query" -> "Dali", MaxItems -> step, 
          "StartIndex" -> idx, "SearchType" -> "Image"}][All, 
        "ImageLink"]]], Break[]];
    idx = idx + step;
    ]];
 Print[Row@{"step = ", step, ", count = ", 
    Length@Flatten@Internal`BagPart[b, All], ", time = ", 
    t}], {step, {1, 2, 10, 50}}]
```

But with the free tier Google blocks you after 100 requests:

[image]

and after 1k results you are blocked for the day:

[image]

***So the question remains how to pull images with StartIndex > 100 in a single day.***

Comment: There is a `StartIndex` parameter right below `MaxItems` in the documentation. Did you try it?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: @C.E. See my updates.

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense but I'm having a hard time deciphering this. You're saying "so the question remains..." as if the problem is partially solved, but you have many error messages, where do they come from? And why is count always 101, shouldn't it be increasing by `step`? It is also unclear if the limit is 100 or 1000.