# Is it possible to search the web by image from Mathematica?

Tags: image, web-access, searching, webservices

Is it possible to perform a web search based on an image input?

There are several services that provide this: Google, Bing, [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/), and maybe others.  I am not sure which can be accessed programmatically and which are the easiest to use from *Mathematica*.

I am looking for the simplest way to take an [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) object in *Mathematica* and search the web for duplicates or highly similar images.  Whichever service is the simplest to access would suit me.

Comment: Based on the Mathematica documentation for Google Custom Search and Bing, image input appears not to be possible with those services. FWIW I did test Google Custom Search while investigating [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124075/731) and even in the web GUI it's not possible to set up a search engine that accepts image input.

Comment: It's not 100% clear (as I'm not very familiar with web technologies), but it seems like Bing should allow it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760791(v=bsynd.50).aspx

Comment: FWIW I agree that Bing appears to be able to take image input and do stuff with it, including finding similar images.

Comment: The [vision API of Google](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/internet-detection) seems to be the closest I could find. But I haven't checked the pricing.